# Ant build successful, yet Eclipse shows errors. (new to Eclipse / Java)

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I've been trying to crash-course myself with Eclipse / Java / Ant (come from 14 years of .Net) and having a hard time wrapping my head around all the build process.

I'm running my ant tasks and it says "Build Successful", yet my packages and various files have a red boxes with a white "X" across them. The file contents have all sorts of complaints in them:

- The declared package does not match the expected package
- The import cannot be resolved
- Etc. etc.

The question is: Why is it that my project can compile "Successfully" (via Ant), yet there are clearly errors that would prevent a project from compiling.

I'm obviously missing something here, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: include your ant script and .classpath in your question -- that will show people how your project is built with ant, and how eclipse tries to build the project (via the .classpath file)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Project Properties dialog in Eclipse and check the Source tab. There needs to be a definition of source folder in the dialog such as `<YourProjectName>/src` or `<YourProjectName>/src/main/java`.

Also check Libraries tab in the same dialog. Make sure that each jar file, or folder of classes are correctly listed in this tab if there is any library dependency.

If you think that those settings above are correct, you may need to **Clean** project and let Eclipse build it again (please see `Project -> Clean` menu for it) as sometimes Eclipse loses synchronization of its view with the filesystem probably because Ant build system can interfere with its build systems depending on the scenario.